# Work out Number of hours still to Complete

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet to keep track of training which I do.  As part of the requirement, I have been given a set number of hours to complete per month (20 hours).

The formula I require is to work out how many hours I still need to complete or number of hours I have exceeded for the month.

```
Column A   Column B           Column C        Column D
Period     Hours completed    Hours Needed    No of Hours Exceeded or Under
```

At the moment I have used the formula in Column D = Col B - Col C.  However, this works only for periods where I have completed more than 20 hours training.  For periods where I have completed less, the formula does not work.

Comment: You need to explain more clearly what you want.  If `B` is 17 and `C` is 20, then your `B`-`C` formula evaluates to `-3`, which strikes me as being the right answer.  Do you want Column `D` to say `3` if `B` is ***either*** 17 or 23?

Answer (score 1):

This issue has most likely occurred because you've formatted your figures as 'Time' values in Excel. And Excel does not do 'negative dates' or 'negative times'. 15:00 is a time of day (3pm); -15:00 is an invalid time of day. If you do subtractions resulting in Negative Times, they will not show.

I would recommend you format your times as regular decimal Numbers, using 1.0 for each full hour and 0.5 for half an hour. These can show negatives where required. If your requirements are more detailed, it might be worth having one or more 'helper' columns to help process your numbers until they output in the sort of format that you're looking for.

Comment: Actually a simple trick is to add a large integer after the calculation. Time's are stored as a percentage of 24hrs. Both 0 and 1 equal midnight. Try adding 10 (my go to) and you'll avoid errors. Having said that I agree with your approach considering this problem may evolve past 24 hours as a requirement.

Comment: Yup, a simple +1 is a decent bare-bones solution to run bulletproof time subtractions, assuming all you need is to show the individual row-by-row results in the desired format. But if you plan to start totalling them at all then you need to account for that additional 24h every single time - ie summing the column would become counter-intuitive because it would look like it was displaying 3h but would sum as 27h. And you'd struggle to get your +1d to show his positive and negative times in the way I would suppose he would like to? Thanks for the thoughts @snoopen